# How render template after post data with ajax in FLASK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have a problem, i cant open render_template after post data with ajax. this is my ajax code.

```
if ($(this).attr("value") == "button-three") {

    var skoring = getRadioVal(document.getElementById('mentodeNegasi'),'negasi')

    $.ajax({
        data: { metodeSkoring: skoring },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/evaluasiModel'
    })
}
```

and this is my server code.

```
@app.route('/evaluasiModel', methods=['POST',"GET"])              
def evaluasiModel():
    metodeSkoring = request.form['metodeSkoring']
    metodeSkoring = int(metodeSkoring)
    return render_template("evaluasiModelKlasifikasi.html", hasilSkoring = metodeSkoring)
```

i hope after post data ajax to "def evaluasiModel()", I can open render_template "evaluasiModelKlasifikasi.html" and get data metodeSkoring to show in this template.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python or flask, but if I understand correctly, the line `return render_template("evaluasiModelKlasifikasi.html", hasilSkoring = metodeSkoring)` returns an html code that you want to show in some place of your main html code. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, correct. but i cant show this html. after i get data from ajax

Comment: Check my answer. You don't speecify where you want to put the html code from the response (inside of a `div`, etc.). I've given you a example adding it to the body

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need that post functionality? You can simply load the page after getting the value from the user using redirect.

Here is an example how to do so. I simulated a similar scenario. For that I needed

1. `application.py` : as route controller
2. `index.html`  : as main template
3. `evaluasiModelKlasifikasi.html` : as redirected template

`application.py`:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def show_index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/evaluasiModel/<metodeSkoring>')              
def evaluasiModel(metodeSkoring):
        return render_template("evaluasiModelKlasifikasi.html", hasilSkoring = metodeSkoring)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="mentodeNegasi" />
        <button id="get_button">Get score</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#get_button").on("click",function(){
                var skoring = $("#mentodeNegasi").val();
                window.location.href = '/evaluasiModel/'+skoring;                           
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`evaluasiModelKlasifikasi.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>evaluasiModel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="result">
            hasilSkoring: {{ hasilSkoring }}        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

index page:

[image: index page]

after redirection:

[image]

Demonstration:

[image]

Comment: thank you sir,  i will try to my code.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the html code from the response in the success function of the ajax call. You don't specify where you want to add that code, so here you have an example adding it to the `body` of your page...

```
if ($(this).attr("value") == "button-three") {

    var skoring = getRadioVal(document.getElementById('mentodeNegasi'),'negasi')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/evaluasiModel'
        data: { metodeSkoring: skoring },
        dataType: 'html'
        success: function(response) {
            $('body').append(response);
        }
    })
}
```